# Resize a container if childs visibility changes (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, resize, visibility

Hy

I'm quite new to jQuery and I can't solve this problem:

I have a `#content` container with 2 infoboxes inside. When clicking on the infobuttons they become visible (via toggle jQuery function).

My problem is, that the size of `#content` does not "resize", I mean, it does not get bigger, so the infoboxes overlap with the next container.

How can I prevent it? Is there a function which resizes containers depending on the visibility of the content?

EDIT:

Sorry for being not precice, here the code:

---

```
  <div id="content">
. . .

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#info_icon').on('click mouseover',(function(){
     $('#info_text').toggle("slow");
  }));
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#project_icon').on('click mouseover',(function(){
     $('#project_text').toggle("slow");
  }));
});
</script>

  <div id="info_text" style="display:none;">
...
  </div>


  <div id="project_text" style="display: none;">  
...
  </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
#content {
    background-color: #b12a28;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    height: auto;
}


#info_text {
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.8;
    float: left;
    height: 40%;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}


#project_text {
    background-color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.8;
    float: left;
    height: 40%;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    clear: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post some code?

Comment: Perhaps you have defined max-height or height? It seems it has sth to do

Comment: solved the problem by adding: overflow: hidden; at the css settings for #content (it was because of floating elements...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you given the container a fixed size in the css?

Comment: floating elements causes that behaviour...this may be of help http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html

Comment: oooh thank you so much! problem solved with overflow: hidden – I would never have guessed that it is because of the floating elements, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The first guess is that there is a way to solve this not with jQuery/javascript but with CSS, but the specifics of your use case weren't illustrated, so it is hard to say.

As for doing it with javascript, perhaps this meta code will help

```
1) Detect KeyStroke event or #content on change
2) Get the size of the various containers your are employing (e.g. $("#content").width(),height, etc)
3) Resize the #content container such that it accommodates both boxes
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a CSS problem that doesn't require javascript to fix. Can you post a link, the code or a jsfiddle?